# AjaxSubmit overwrite form field before send

Tags: ajax, jquery, jqueryform

I would like to overwrite the value of the "password" field before submiting a form on Jquery using AjaxSubmit function.
I know I can just update the value on the input field but, I don't want the user to see this transformation. In other words, I just want to send a custom value to the password field and keep the current value on the screen...

How could I do that?

My current code:

```
var loginoptions = { 
    success: mySuccessFuction, 
    dataType: 'json'
}

$('#My_login_form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var pass=$("#My_login_form_password").val();
    if (pass.length>0){
        loginoptions.data={
            password: ($.sha1($("#My_login_form_csrf").val()+$.sha1(pass)))
        }
    $("#My_login_form").ajaxSubmit(loginoptions);
    delete loginoptions.data;
});
```

The problem with this code is that it is sending a "password" POST variable with the form field value and, a duplicated one with the value I set on "loginoptions.data".

Comment: You could just use jQuery.post instead of the ajaxform plugin. Then you would have better control over what data gets sent.

Comment: I don't think you need to hash the password clientside. For mtim-attacks it makes no difference whether you send the clear password or just the hash. In every case you need to hash and salt the password serverside. Mostly it's safer to use an existing authentication module anyways.

Comment: I would preferer to use ajaxSubmit function but, if there's no way of doing that, I think I would change it to post has you say Andbdrew.

Comment: @Christoph I'm generating a salt (csrf) for each form request. The password sent is a result of hash(password)+hash(salt) and it's different in each request. Does it still vulnerable to MITM attacks?

Comment: yes it is. It makes no difference, the attacker gets either the password or the hash so he can authenticate himself to the server with either the password or the hash. If you are really concerned about safety, you need to use SSL. If you are not, it's okay to just send the password and do all the security stuff serverside  (hashing, timeouts and so on).

Comment: But how could he authenticate with one time hash? I really don't want to use SSL here but, I was trying to give at least, a minimal protection xD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that ajaxSubmit uses the **serialize()** function of jquery on the form and then, adds the extra data serialized too. So, if I have a field named "password" with the value "1234" and then try to change that to "abcd", using "loginoptions.data.password", it will serialize everything and put the "options.data" like this:

```
"password=1234&field_2=value_2&password=abcd"
```

After many tries, I gave up on using ajaxSubmit function and decided to use ajax function to submit the form:

```
var the_form=$('form#My_login_form');
loginoptions.url=the_form.attr("action");
loginoptions.type=the_form.attr("method");
var serializedForm=decodeURIComponent(the_form.serialize());
loginoptions.data=serializedForm.deserializeToObject();
var pass=$("#My_login_form_password").val();
    if (pass.length>0){
        loginoptions.data.password= ($.sha1($("#My_login_form_csrf").val()+$.sha1(pass)));
    }
$.ajax(loginoptions);
```

Here is the **deserializeToObject()** function:

```
function deserializeToObject (){
    var result = {};
    this.replace(
        new RegExp("([^?=&]+)(=([^&]*))?", "g"),
        function($0, $1, $2, $3) { result[$1] = $3; }
    )
    return result;
}

String.prototype.deserializeToObject = deserializeToObject;
```

Answer (score 2):

Building off of Cristiano's answer, I was able to get this to work. If you use `:beforeSubmit()`, the changed value doesn't post, but if you use the `:beforeSerialize()`, it posts the changed value.

```
         $('#ff').ajaxForm({
            beforeSerialize:function(jqForm, options){
                var serializedForm = decodeURIComponent(jqForm.serialize());
                options.data = serializedForm.deserializeToObject();
                options.data.tPassword = MD5($("#tPassword").val())     
            },
            success:function(data){
               // do stuff
            }
         });
```

Comment: Didn't remembered that method. I think that maybe it could be added to the plugin in a future version?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it anyhow then I think you can use callback function `beforeSubmit: function(contentArray, $form, options){}`

```
  beforeSubmit: function(contentArray, $form, options){ 
    for(var i=0; i<contentArray.length; i++){
      if(contentArray[i].name == "password") {
        contentArray[i].value = ($.sha1($("#My_login_form_csrf").val()+$.sha1(pass)))
      } 
    }
  }
```

Comment: It doesn't work... If I make a console.log of contentArray, it shows fine but, when I see the request, it doesn't have the changes applied... Now just shows the password without changes.

Comment: ohh, try to check and modify, `options.data` instead of `contentArray`, may be it works

Comment: It didn't work too... If I make "console.log(options.data);" it gives me "undefined" but, if i make "console.log(options);", I could see a serialized string in options.data...